# WCF ServiceClient Code Generation fails when types in Catel.Core dll are reused (including small example project)

Tags: catel

today I created a new Project, using Catel Framework in Silverlight.

However - I am facing a Problem when generating the service-Client for the WCF-Service in the silverlight Project.

To reproduce the issue:
- open solution,

- build
- "Show all files" in the Silverlight Project (CatelWCF.Problem)
- Observe:

  - beneath node "WCFService" in Reference.cs - all Code generated successfully
- now "configure service-reference" (right click "WCFService", Configure)
- choose radio-button Option "Reuse types in all referenced assemblies", followed by OK (before it was configured to use all but Catel.Core)
- Observe:

  - error-message in Error-List
  - view file "Reference.cs" - it is empty.

In WPF there is no Problem whatsoever, even if all assemblies are referenced. (CatelWCF.Problem.WPFClient Project)

Any ideas?

Johannes Colmsee

Update:

Sorry, the demo-Project can be downloaded here:

[Demo](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=F8DF0DE4DFA37CA6!112&authkey=!AILVkIumQr1Io2s&ithint=file%2C7z)

Update2: About why "observe" #1 Shows a succesfully generated file: "Catel.Core.dll" is explicitly excluded from referenced assemblies when you open the Project.

Answer (score 0):

I narrowed down the Problem to one specific type in Catel.Core dll - Geert, please check what is wrong with this class:

Catel.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.XmlSerializationContextInfo

Regards

Johannes Colmsee

Update: Creating a sample Project with a (almost exact) copy of that class - no Problems.